# How to add two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I am trying to append one dataframe to another

```
Name    roll_no   House
John    A_1        Red
Mark    A_2        Green
Twain   N_1        Yellow
Mark    A_2        Red
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat both using `pd.concat` and then remove duplicates rows using `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates()
    Name   ID   House
0   John  A_1     Red
1   Mark  A_2     Red
2  Twain  N_1  Yellow
1   Mark  A_2   Green
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
>>> df2.merge(df1, how='outer')
    Name   ID   House
0   John  A_1     Red
1   Mark  A_2   Green
2  Twain  N_1  Yellow
3   Mark  A_2     Red
```